# How do I use GetConsoleDisplayMode in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

**Background**

I'm working with the console and PInvokes in C#, just to see what magic you can do when you're not limiting yourself to the .NET framework. I stumbled upon a function in Kernel32 called GetConsoleDisplayMode that basically lets you see if the console is running in windowed, full-screen or hardware full-screen mode. The documentation for this function can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsoledisplaymode).

GetConsoleDisplayMode takes only one parameter: an LPDWORD in which the display mode can be stored. The function returns a bool, indicating the success of the call. [According to this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx), an LPDWORD is a pointer to a DWORD, which in turn is simply a 32-bit unsigned integer (*uint32* in C#).

So, from what I understand from the docs is that this should work:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetConsoleDisplayMode", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetConsoleDisplayMode(ref uint lpModeFlags);

static void Main(string[] args) {
    uint mode = 0;
    var success = GetConsoleDisplayMode(ref mode);

    Console.WriteLine(success);
    Console.WriteLine(mode);

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

However, the function always returns false!

**What I have tried**

Of course I have tried to modify the code, in hopes of getting it to work properly.

A call to GetLastError() returns the most curious error code 3221684230 of which even [Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=GetConsoleDisplayMode%203221684230) and [Microsoft Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx) have no knowledge (nor is it uint.MaxValue or int.MaxValue, I have checked). This does not get me a step further, so I dropped this option.

Another thing I've tried (in the hopes that I had read or understood the documentation incorrectly) is changing *ref* to *out*, which passes an uninitialized variable for the function to initialize for me:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetConsoleDisplayMode", ExactSpelling = false, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool GetConsoleDisplayMode(out uint lpModeFlags);

static void Main(string[] args) {
    var success = GetConsoleDisplayMode(out var mode);
    if (!success) {
        Console.WriteLine(Kernel32.GetLastError());
    }

    Console.WriteLine(success);
    Console.WriteLine(mode);

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Alas, this too was unsuccessful and, interestingly, produces the same error code.

**My question(-s)**

Why does my call to GetConsoleDisplayMode always return false, why does GetLastError return such an obscure error code and most importantly: how do I find the error that's bugging me and/or get this to work?

**More information**

I am running Windows 10 x64 build 1709 (Fall Creators Update).

Maybe [this excerpt](https://books.google.nl/books?id=1K-nJd1ZUv0C&pg=PA145&lpg=PA145&dq=getconsoledisplaymode%20not%20working&source=bl&ots=YbNzjVFcsj&sig=tqQVTFHT6jbFSLgBn1M1U0NUKTk&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiRldv0xrXZAhVLLcAKHaB4BBUQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=getconsoledisplaymode%20not%20working&f=false) from John Paul Mueller's book on the Windows API and the .NET framework can be of help (that's about the best documentation of GetConsoleDisplayMode that I can find).

Comment: 3221684230 is xC007006 - invalid handle

Comment: what type of c# app. Not allowed for UWP

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I can work with that error code. As for the type of app, it is a .NET framework console app, there is no UWP involved.

Comment: This simple definition `[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)] public static extern bool GetConsoleDisplayMode(out int lpModeFlags);` would be more correct. But it doesn't change the result. Even in C/C++ this call returns false in Windows 10, don't know why. So, it's not a p/invoke issue.

Comment: Ok, so it might be a bug in the console API. I might have to look for an ISO of an older version of Windows so I can test if it's me or the API.

Comment: Are you building it as a 32 or 64-bit app?